# What's the raw dictionary in Image I/O?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, exif

The Image I/O framework on iOS uses dictionaries to store image metadata.

One of these dictionaries is called [kCGImagePropertyRawDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/reference/imageio/kcgimagepropertyrawdictionary). The documentation says:

> A dictionary of key-value pairs for an image that contains minimally
>   processed, or raw, data.

What does this mean? What processing is being skipped when we access this dictionary that is being done when we access, say, the [EXIF dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/reference/imageio/kcgimagepropertyexifdictionary)?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer on what exactly this is and how to save metadata in this dictionary?

Comment: @CanLeloğlu No.

Comment: @CanLeloğlu Did you try printing out the content of this dictionary to see how it's different from other dictionaries?

Comment: I could not find any sample images that has this metadata. The keywork in image i/o is there to actually modify this portion of the image however after trying for hours I could not manage to change raw dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, but what did you mean by "the keywork in image i/o is there to actually modify this portion of the image"?

Comment: sorry I made a typo there. I meant that I thought the keyword(kCGImagePropertyRawDictionary) exists to change metadata. but after trying many times I haven't seen any effects of using this keyword.